# How can I list all the terms of a given vocabulary using Views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I just need to list all the terms of the "Colors" vocabulary using the Drupal 7 version of Views. I thought it was simple to do it, but I can't find a way to get it.

I can't use contextual filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build the view from a taxonomy base as shown in this screenshot (I'm showing Tags; you would need to show Colors):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Funny. I answered [a similar question with a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878907/drupal-7-get-a-list-of-taxonomy-terms-in-views/7914112#7914112) (and image) on Stackoverflow a while back, so had a sense of *deja vu* when seeing this question and response.

Of course you can also add a block or page display in the first step (see [image I provided for the earlier question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ftv.png) of this nature -- again using "tag" instead of "color")

If you aren't already pretty used to Views, it can help to experiment and learn about the different "display format" options.